# How can I enable process control extension (PCNTL) in PHP MAMP?

Tags: php, mamp, pcntl

I have [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) and I need to enable `-pcntl` on my current MAMP installation.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 59):

There is a way of compiling PCNTL as an extension and linking it in to an existing PHP build, but it's a bit in-depth.

I'm doing the following on [Mac OS X v10.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard) (64 bit), with MAMP and PHP version 5.3.6. Remember to change PHP version numbers in the following lines if yours is different!

Please note that `make` *is required*, which isn't installed by default on Mac OS X. You need to install this via [Mac developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/unix/).

First, download a tar of the PHP source code that matches the version you are using in MAMP (e.g., mine is 5.3.6), which you can do at *[Unsupported Historical Releases](http://www.php.net/releases/)*. Untar and CD to *php-[version]/ext/pcntl*, e.g.:

```
wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.3.6.tar.gz
tar xvf php-5.3.6.tar.gz
cd php-5.3.6/ext/pcntl
```

You then need to run `phpize` in the pcntl directory, which is a binary file that comes with MAMP:

```
cd php-5.3.6/ext/pcntl
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpize
```

This creates a bunch of files that are needed for preparing a extension for compiling.

We now need to add some flags to tell it to compile the library with dual 32-bit and 64-bit architecture, as the MAMP PHP has been built this way. If you don't do this, the compiled shared objects won't work.

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp"
CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load"
export CFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS CCFLAGS MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
```

We can then run `./configure` and `make` to build our shared object:

```
./configure
make
```

This puts a file called `pcntl.so` in the *modules* directory. Copy this file to your MAMP's PHP extensions directory:

```
cp modules/pcntl.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

Finally, edit the PHP INI file to include the extension:

```
echo "extension=pcntl.so" >> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini
```

PCNTL should now be enabled. To check to see whether it has been added, just run:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php --ri pcntl
```

Output:

```
pcntl

pcntl support => enabled
```

If you see that, it's worked! If anything has gone wrong you can just remove the `pcntl.so` file from the MAMP PHP extensions directory and remove the INI setting, and try again.

Comment: This solution also works for standard PHP that comes with Snow Leopard ^_^

Comment: If you encounter `error: ‘PHP_FE_END’ undeclared here (not in a function)` after running `make`, replace all occurrences of `PHP_FE_END` in pcntl.c with `{NULL,NULL,NULL}`.

Comment: Any clue, I am getting Zend/zend_signal.h doe not exist. When I checked it does exists.

Comment: If you have multiple versions of php on your system (as is the case in Lion), you may need to specify the `php-config` location when on the `./configure` step. That will look something like: `./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php-config`

Comment: @jverdi thanks. your tip worked for me... Also if someone is getting compilation error in pcntl.c file, replace HASH_KEY_NON_EXISTENT with HASH_KEY_NON_EXISTANT

Comment: Is it possible to make this available to PHP via the command line? I am calling php through the one MAMP installs but the module still doesn't exist after doing this.  It made it available to the one that apache is using however.

Comment: @kyle the MAMP PHP and CLI PHP use different INIs, so check that the extension is enabled in both.

Comment: Works with php7.2.14 even in 2019 !

Answer (score 5):

If you have [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable `brew`) installed on your Mac then you should be able to do:

```
brew install php53-pcntl
```

I am no expert on MAMP though.

```
brew install php53-pcntl
brew info php53-pcntl
```

Output:

```
Warning: php53-pcntl-5.3.25 already installed

php53-pcntl: stable 5.3.25
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php
/usr/local/Cellar/php53-pcntl/5.3.23 (3 files, 32K)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/php53-pcntl/5.3.25 (3 files, 32K) *
  Built from source
https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/commits/master/Formula/php53-pcntl.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf
Required: php53
==> Options
--without-config-file
    Do not add ext-pcntl.ini to /usr/local/etc/php/5.3/conf.d
--without-homebrew-php
    Ignore homebrew PHP and use default instead
==> Caveats
To finish installing pcntl for PHP 5.3:
  * /usr/local/etc/php/5.3/conf.d/ext-pcntl.ini was created,
    do not forget to remove it upon extension removal.
  * Restart your webserver.
  * Write a PHP page that calls "phpinfo();"
  * Load it in a browser and look for the info on the pcntl module.
  * If you see it, you have been successful!
```

Comment: No such brew formula exists

Comment: Yes it does.. You need to do your research better before down voting.

Comment: this depends on the BREW version of PHP being installed - it does not appear to play well with MAMP - which was the original question

Comment: It works fine with my MAMP version (with php 5.6.1) apart from php56-pcntl is kinda buggy right now and brew can't install it.

Comment: This works with MAMP. Just install `phpXX-pcntl` first, and than copy the `pcntl.so` to the correct folder (Check the output of brew for the correct path):
`cp /usr/local/Cellar/php71-pcntl/7.1.8_15/pcntl.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/`

Answer (score 3):

Just to make my life easier, I made a script [from the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432855/445410). I used it to add extensions pcntl, sysvmsg, sysvshm, sysvsem and others to MAMP. To use it, [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to the extension directory or pass the directory as an argument to the script. Example: *./addExtension.sh php-5.3.6/ext/pcntl*

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$1
MAMP_PHP=$2
if [ -z "$DIR" ]
then
  DIR=`pwd`
fi

if [ -z "$MAMP_PHP" ]
then
  MAMP_PHP='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6'
fi

EXTENSION=${DIR##*/}

echo Extension: $EXTENSION

cd $DIR

eval "${MAMP_PHP}/bin/phpize"


MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp"
CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load"
export CFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS CCFLAGS MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

./configure
make

cp modules/${EXTENSION}.so "${MAMP_PHP}/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/"

PHP_INI_PATH="${MAMP_PHP}/conf/php.ini"
sed -e "/extension=${EXTENSION}.so/ d" $PHP_INI_PATH > TMP
mv TMP $PHP_INI_PATH
echo "extension=${EXTENSION}.so" >> $PHP_INI_PATH

eval "${MAMP_PHP}/bin/php --ri ${EXTENSION}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by using [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts).

I ran the command:

```
sudo port install php5-pcntl
```

Comment: Give more explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found some slightly different instructions that worked for [Mac OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite) and MAMP using PHP 5.6.2.

Instructions were found here:
*[How to get Artisan Tinker Working in OS X 10 MAMP](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/01/get-artisan-tinker-working-osx-10-mamp/)*

```
wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.6.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf php-5.6.2.tar.gz
mv php-5.6.2 php
mkdir -p /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include
mv php /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include

cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include/php
./configure

MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp"
CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load"
export CFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS CCFLAGS MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

cd ext/pcntl
phpize
./configure
make
cp modules/pcntl.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download a PHP implementation from *[Unsupported Historical Releases](https://www.php.net/releases/)*
2. `tar -xzvf php-7.3.8.tar.gz` (we will name the outputted folder `PhpSrcFolder`)
3. Make sure you've got the MAMP bin directory in your path → `echo $PATH`. You'll need the extra tools it has in order to do this. (Skip to step 5 if you already have mamp's bin in you $PATH.)
4. you can add MAMP's bin to your path as follow, we first grep the version of PHP's used by MAMP from `~/.profile` (PS: MAMP add alias to php in the latter), then we add the MAMP bin to PATH in accordance with the version used.

   ```
   export PHP_VERSION=`grep "alias php" ~/.profile | cut -d"/" -f6 | cut -c4-`
   \# point to your php.ini folder to use the same php setting
   export PHPRC="/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/"
   export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php$PHP_VERSION/bin:$PATH

   ### PS: close and reopen terminal
   ```
5. Copy `PhpSrcFolder`/ext/pcntl to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/include/php/ext/pcntl`
6. Go into `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/include/php/ext/pcntl` and then run the `phpize` command. Note that you'll also need to have Xcode and related tools installed.
7. You should then be able to run `./configure && make && make install`. This will build the extension in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/include/php/ext/pcntl/modules/pcntl.so`, copy it and paste it in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pcntl.so`
8. Now, edit the *php.ini* and enable the module like you would any of the other extensions. Get path of `php.ini` loaded by running `which php`for me its : `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php7.3.8.ini` and recheck that it has the pcntl extension:

   ```
   [pcntl]

   extension=pcntl.so
   ```