# pcntl installation problems on MAMP 2.1.1 (Mac OS X lion)

Tags: php, macos, mamp, php-extension, pcntl

I have a problem with pcntl installation. My PHP version is 5.4.4, I followed this tutorial:
http://cyberpunx.com/2011/11/pcntl-so-on-osx-lion-and-mamp/

But Pcntl does not load. In php error log I see:

> [04-Sep-2012 22:58:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pcntl: Unable to
>   initialize module Module compiled with module API=20090626 PHP
>   compiled with module API=20100525 These options need to match

How can I compile pcntl correctly? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Refer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230255/how-to-enable-process-control-extension-pcntl-in-php-mamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230255/how-to-enable-process-control-extension-pcntl-in-php-mamp)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely scenario is that after the upgrade you forgot to update your `php.ini` to change the `extension_dir`.

If you have followed the tutorial to the letter, your `extension_dir` should be:

```
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
```

Also, don't forget to restart Apache after your `php.ini` changes.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, my solution was completely different. I removed MAMP and activated OSX built-in apache and installed MySQL.

This tutorial helped me a lot:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server

Then I followed this:
http://cyberpunx.com/2011/11/pcntl-so-on-osx-lion-and-mamp/

...and finally got pcntl working!

//EDIT:

another very easy solution is to download precompiled PHP for mac:
http://php-osx.liip.ch/

Comment: Hi Martin, glad everything is working for you. But the question was explicitly for MAMP so we need to get answer for MAMP rather then changing our environment. If possible could you please un-accept your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Owl pity that the bounty expired over this answer :(

Comment: @Jack, Sorry mate. I got stuck with work and completely forgot :(, HOwever I haven't tested your answer though. I hope Martin has given a shot before he changed the environment.

Comment: @Owl I couldn't test it myself either, because I mainly develop on Win :)